# Are Orange Classifiers Thread-Safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, orange

I'm making use of the Orange Data Mining Suite in a Python program, I get a Classifier from a Learner and what I want to know is it possible to then use that Classifier in a multi-threaded environment ?

Basically I want to classify a set of results in parallel to make use of multiple CPUs I have at my disposal.

If this depends on the Classifier , the two I am most concerned about are Orange.classification.neural.NeuralNetworkClassifier and Orange.classification.tree.TreeClassifier (specifically the one returned by SimpleTreeLearner)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably yes. I wrote most of the C++ code and I don't think I did any non-thread safe stuff. Actually, you've chosen exactly the two classifiers that are not mine (TreeClassifier is, but SimpleTreeClassifier is not). If their authors followed the general design, they should be safe (I mean the classifiers, not the authors :).

How do you run Python in parallel - despite the global interpreter lock? When we do stuff in parallel, we usually just start separate processes.